# Apache POI full workbook copy

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, xlsx

Have an issue with Apache POI (3.8 final release).

My task: create some xls/xlsx files according data from basic xls/xlsx document.

First of all, I try to copy some data (Cell, CellStyle and etc) from base document to destinations document through `CellStyle.cloneFrom`. It looks good, but when I opened xlsx file (`xl/styles.xml`) I found that it had different count of style (and fonts) than my source document.

Can I create full copy of source xls/xlsx document via POI API?

Code that create template of base document and create new document:

```
public WorkbookTemplate constructTemplate(Workbook wb)
{
    //copy styles from template
    styles = new HashSet<CellStyle>(wb.getNumCellStyles());
    for (short i = 0; i < wb.getNumCellStyles(); i++)
    {
        styles.add(wb.getCellStyleAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(wb.getNumCellStyles());

    for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
    {
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);
        SheetTemplate sheetTemplate = new SheetTemplate(this);
        sheets.add(sheetTemplate.constructTemplate(sheet));
    }

    return this;
}

public Workbook applyTemplate(Workbook wb, JXPathContext context)
{
    preProcessOfWorkBook(wb);
    System.out.println(wb.getNumCellStyles());

    for (SheetTemplate sheetTemplate : sheets)
    {
        Sheet newSheet = wb.createSheet(sheetTemplate.getSheetName());
        sheetTemplate.applyTemplate(newSheet, context);
    }

    return wb;
}

public void preProcessOfWorkBook(Workbook wb)
{
    //Transfer of CellStyles
    styleConvert = new HashMap<CellStyle, CellStyle>(styles.size());
    for (CellStyle style : styles)
    {
        CellStyle bufStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        bufStyle.cloneStyleFrom(style);
        styleConvert.put(style, bufStyle);
    }
}
```

It's part of WorkbookTemplate class, constructTemplate - creates it, and applyTemplate - transfers data from template to Workbook instance

Comment: put your code here, dont just explain it.

Comment: Why can't you just take a copy of the file, open the copy, write the changes into it and save?

Comment: Because i need caching of template. Of course, i can use VFS cache system, but it leads me to parse source document every time I make a transformation